# Nonconvergence of some parameters in MCMC of Hierarchical Bayesian Model

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, hierarchical-bayesian

**In short:**
MCMC is used to construct posterior distributions for parameters of central tendency and all parameters used in the formula for this central tendency. I only care about the parameters of central tendency which will readily converge. However, several upstream parameters do not converge. Should I worry about this?

**More details:**
I work with a Hierarchical Bayesian Model in which an exponential fit is applied to a dose-response curve constructed for each sample of a set of 100+ samples.

Given the fitting parameters, a dose is determined from a measured response. These 100+ doses are then used to calculate parameters of central tendency. I use MCMC to derive posteriors for all these parameters.

I only care about the parameters of central tendency, and these will readily converge by visual inspection and Rubin & Gelman diagnostics. But many of the exponential fit parameters will not converge. Should I be worried about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not converge"? This question is unclear as the MCMC sampler reproduces a distribution, no an estimator.